# running python on windows using Kivy i get the following errors

Tags: python

i just start tou use Kivy  i try some code

```
from kivy.tests.common
 import GraphicUnitTest 
class MyTestCase(GraphicUnitTest): 
    def test_runtouchapp(self):
 # non-integrated approach      
        from kivy.app import runTouchApp        
        from kivy.uix.button
        import Button   
        button = Button()       
        runTouchApp(button)
```

code find on a tutorial but i have errors

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\ZACHARIE\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-02-01_4.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
```

Comment: I understand why this gives errors... code is not formatted as a starter. I'm missing the reference to the original code and the effort in finding a solution to your problem. You should mention something about what you tried! And finish the tour!

Comment: ''code find on a tutorial but i have errors'' --


Do you mind linking the tutorial? It seems pretty awful. The most commonly referred to tutorial is Alexander Taylor's ['Kivy Crash Course'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7UKmK9eQLY&list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be jumping into the deep end, firstly you should typically always put your imports at the very top of your python file.

Then in kivy, you need at least your main widget class and your app class:

e.g

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MainWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

When you run this file, you should see an empty window. Afterwards, you need to look into defining kivy widgets with kv lang.